# Select Record with Repeated Status using Sql Query

Tags: asp.net, sql

i have one Schedule Table like
[image]

i want to look like select query data is:

1 and 11 is Duplicate trainer and Duplicate day,time

10 and 12 is Duplicate trainer, Duplicate vanueid and Duplicate date,time

so last two column are display is not Duplicate than available and is Duplicate than display notavailable
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]Here is the solution that is coming to my mind.There may some syntax issue but i given the logic which may help you.

```
        DECLARE @duplicate TABLE ( 
        trainerId INT,
        dt varchar(50)
        )

          INSERT INTO @duplicate SELECT TrainerId , [Date] from tbl GROUP BY TrainerId , Date HAVING (COUNT(*) > 1)
         SELECT * FROM @duplicate
         DECLARE @tempTable TABLE (
             trainerId INT,
             dt varchar(50),
             status int
          )
          INSERT INTO @tempTable   
          SELECT trainerId , [Date]  , STATUS = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @duplicate  where           trainerId = tbl.TrainerId and dt = tbl.Date) FROM tbl
          ![enter image description here][2]SELECT * ,  CASE [status] WHEN 0 THEN 'Available' ELSE 'Not Available' END FROM @tempTable
```

Comment: thanks devesh but not getting. if possible than give me a perfect query.

Comment: @Ketanmevada i have put the working code and also added the sample data and output from the query. You need to adjust to your column name and other stuffs.

Comment: can u give me a query with time ,like same time trainer is not available  
Means example is :
if in this example record 1 and 11 is same date and same trainer but if is time is diffrent than he is available